# How to display rows from a Ms Access database on to a GUI as an Editable table using C#

Tags: c#, database, ms-access

I was working on a project on taking attendance using face detection and recognition  project and i just want to display the list of name and ID of students with a row showing absent and present. I want the tables' row that shows absent and present editable. So that I can change a student's presence if I can see him/her present from the photo but not recognized with recognizer. Any idea or sample codes please?

Comment: If you can't do something as simple as showing some data in a DataGrid, then you're really far away from being able to implement face recognition.

Comment: I already did the face detection and recognition that uses Emgu CV wrapper class. I am not well experienced with .Net framework.I was doing face detection and recognition with open cv. I eventually needed a user interface for easier communcation between the user and my application so i just have to migrate to wrapper classes that uses C# or VB which i am not well familiar with except the basics.So if i have to implement 'Project crashing' then i have to reach for you guys (Time is the constraint that i cant go through books).I hope you understand.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You will want to create an observable ViewModel of the student data.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh821028.aspx (This is for silverlight, but same for WPF basically)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx (For WPF)

The observable ViewModel (INotify...) will let WPF know when data is changed and it will update itself automatically.

Good luck! :)